# Add space between seglistitems in docbook

Tags: margin, padding, docbook

When rendering the following DocBook XML there is no additional space between two different `seglistitem` so it is quite hard to distinguish one entry from the other when reading. How can I add some spacing between the items (not between the fields of an item)?

```
<segmentedlist>
  <segtitle>Field 1</segtitle>
  <segtitle>Field 2</segtitle>
  <seglistitem>
    <seg>First item</seg><seg>Some data</seg>
  </seglistitem>
  <seglistitem>
    <seg>Second item</seg><seg>Some data</seg>
  </seglistitem>
</segmentedlist>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using DocBook-XSL:

#### HTML output

[Create a CSS file](http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/UsingCSS.html) that includes a rule for the `seglistitem` class:

```
.seglistitem {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
             }
```

#### PDF output

Customize the "seglistitem" template (see lists.xsl) by adding a suitable `margin-bottom` (or `space-after`) value:

```
<xsl:template match="seglistitem">
  <xsl:variable name="id">
    <xsl:call-template name="object.id"/>
  </xsl:variable>
  <fo:block id="{$id}" margin-bottom="10px">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```